# Jqgrid filesize formatter for Mb/kb format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, filesize

Is there a formatter Option for showing Kb or Mb file size in `JQ Grid` ?

```
jQuery().ready(function ($) {
         var colModel = [     
                        { name: 'Size', index: 'Size', sortable: false, search: false, align: 'left', width: 100, formatoptions: {suffix:'kb'} },
                         ];
```

This doesn't seems to work ?
Please Help....

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
formatter:'currency',formatoptions:{ decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: "", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "", suffix:" kb"}
```

I had some issues in decimal points that's why I am using `decimalSeparator,thousandsSeparator` and `decimalPlaces`, use it as per your requirements

Comment: You are welcome, If the answer helped to fix your issue then accept it as answer